# How to flexibly select a region with nodes with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The brush function in d3 is great and simple to use. However, for a complex graph like a force-directed tree and scatter plot graph, more flexible selection of nodes may be necessary to understand the property of a particular region.

Is there any way to implement such kind of selection in D3?

[image: flexible selection of multiple nodes]

Comment: No, there's no direct support for this.

Comment: Is that possible to implement this function?

Comment: Yes, although that wouldn't be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a D3 plugin called [lasso.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/lasso) which seems to provide the functionality you are looking for. The [example](http://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/511c5b658c405ad68941) looks like the graphic you attached to your post.

Another one worth a look is the [Polybrush](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3732612) plugin which provides a polygon selection. This, however, might be to restrictive for your needs.